# Can I use the 1.8 inch TFT LCD SD slot for other purposes other than displaying images on the display?

Tags: arduino, display, sd

Can I use the 1.8 inch TFT LCD SD slot for other purposes other than displaying images on the display? For example, storing text files on that SD card (that's on the display's SD slot)? Can I use that display SD card slot like a normal SD card slot (no images, no bitmaps). Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Avoid asking "can I..." because we know nothing about your skills. Maybe I can do it but you cannot since you lack certain skills. What "1.8 inch TFT LCD SD slot "? Include a link to the thing you're asking about. There are combined LCD + SD card reader modules available. These are just **two separate circuits** on the same PCB. You can use the LCD without using the SD reader etc. The SD card reader can be used to store any **data**. From an SD card reader viewpoint how can there be a difference between data that is **text** or data that represents an **image**?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Is it possible to use this' SD card slot https://www.amazon.co.uk/AZDelivery-Display-Pixels-Arduino-Raspberry/dp/B078J5TS2G/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=1.8+inch+TFT+LCD&qid=1583745151&s=computers&sr=1-3 as this https://www.amazon.co.uk/AZDelivery-Reader-Memory-Adapter-Arduino/dp/B06X1DX5WS/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=SPI+Micro+SD+card+module&qid=1583745234&s=computers&sr=1-5 (Do I need to buy a separate SPI Micro SD card module like in the second link or I can substitute it with the already-embedded on in the first link?)

Comment: My **guess** (no guarantee, I have not used this device myself) is that, as I said, the TFT and SD card reader are **completely separate** so yes you can use the SD card reader on the TFT module **as if it was a separate SD card reader module**. The TFT and the card reader use separate chips, they only share some connections. But again: **no guarantees**.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Okay thanks. I'll take your word for it, you seem like a cool person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the display uses I2C communication. the SD card uses SPI communication. they are two independent devices on the module. the SPI pins for the SD module are on the left side on the picture.

[image]